# Convert rows to columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

How can I do the following please?

[image]

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Comment: Post the table structure that you are working with as well as what Yogendra asked.

Comment: How did you determine that you want `C 10 18 0 9` and not (say) `C 18 10 9 0`?

Comment: I use Microsoft SQL Server Express.

Comment: Dear ruakh,no particular order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [**`PIVOT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) table operator to do transform the rows of these course's grades into column, like so:

```
SELECT  
  Course, 
  [1] AS "Grade 1", 
  [2] AS "Grade 2", 
  [3] AS "Grade 3", 
  [4] AS "Grade 4"
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    Course, 
    Grade, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Course 
                      ORDER BY COURSE) rownum 
  FROM Grades
) t
PIVOT 
(
   MAX(Grade)
   FOR rownum IN([1], [2], [3], [4])
) p;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b946/13)

This will give you:

```
COURSE    GRADE 1   GRADE 2      GRADE 3     GRADE 4
  A         15        17          (null)     (null)
  B         12      (null)        (null)     (null)
  C         10        18            0           9
```

**Note that:** I used the ranking function [**`ROW_NUMBER()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) with `PARTITION BY Course` to partition them into four grades. So that you could then group them into these four groups.

If you need to this dynamically, in case there was unknown number of grades. You can use dynamic SQL in this case to generate the list of grades dynamically like so:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' 
                        + QUOTENAME('Grade ' 
                        + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Course 
                                               ORDER BY Course) AS VARCHAR(10)))
                FROM Grades
                         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                      ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 'SELECT Course, ' + @cols +  
                'FROM
                 (
                   SELECT 
                     Course, 
                     Grade, 
                     ''Grade '' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() 
                                       OVER(PARTITION BY Course 
                                ORDER BY COURSE) AS VARCHAR(10)) rownum 
                   FROM Grades
                 ) t
                 PIVOT 
                 (
                   MAX(Grade)
                   FOR rownum IN(' + @cols + ')' +
                ') p';
execute(@query);
```

### [Dynamic SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1bbe7/1)

Comment: i would change row_number with dense_rank() so if there were double 15 marks it wont show in pivot like
dense_rank() OVER(PARTITION BY Course ORDER BY grade)