# Sorting columns to be multi-row

Tags: sql-server

I have data in SQL Server like this:

```
   floor |  Apartment
   1           1 
   1           2 
   1           3 
   2           4 
   2           5 
   2           6
```

because one floor has 3 apartments, I want to sort or convert the `Apartment` column to be a row like the flowing

```
   4   |   5   |   6 
   1   |   2   |   3
```

Comment: Same question here... `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663264/convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! That way, you don't need any of those messy `&nbsp;` and `<br />` tags, either!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6e17/1)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
create table YourTable
(
  Floor int,
  Apartment int
)

go

insert into YourTable values
(   1,           1),
(   1,           2),
(   1,           3),
(   2,           4),
(   2,           5),
(   2,           6)
```

**Query 1**:

```
select P.Floor,
       P.[1] as Room1,
       P.[2] as Room2,
       P.[3] as Room3
from (
     select Floor,
            Apartment,
            row_number() over(partition by Floor order by Apartment) as rn
     from YourTable
     ) as T
pivot(min(T.Apartment) for T.rn in ([1], [2], [3])) as P
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6e17/1/0)**:

```
| FLOOR | ROOM1 | ROOM2 | ROOM3 |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|     1 |     1 |     2 |     3 |
|     2 |     4 |     5 |     6 |
```