# PIVOT in SQL using row value as Column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table, say Maintable like this.

[image]

I want to view this table like this:

[image]

How can this be achieved using dynamic SQL?

Comment: did you write some code .?

Comment: All of those duplicates give you the answer on how to pivot your data, however, [SQL server : Convert rows into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589282/sql-server-convert-rows-into-columns) is very likely the one you want here (just with a `GROUP BY` which the others teach you). [Convert rows to columns in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663264/convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql) demonstrates it well though and includes a dynamic approach.

Comment: If you try, and failed to implement to solution, the post a new question with **consumable** data (not images) and show your attempt(s) and explain why they didn't work.